# Retrieve two var values from Slider Widget?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to implement [Jquery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range) with ranges.
However, I can't seem to find any two variables to get values from this:

```
    $( "#entrance-price" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    values: [ 0, 500 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#entrance-price-amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
    }
});
$( "#entrance-price-amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#entrance-price" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
    " - $" + $( "#entrance-price" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
```

Normally, I would do

```
var From = $("#from").val();
var To = $("#to").val();
```

But here it seems there is `#entrance-price`0 and `#entrance-price`1.
How would I go about getting these two values? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
var from = $("#entrance-price").slider("values", 0);
var to   = $("#entrance-price").slider("values", 1);
```

Comment: Thanks bartjel! That's exactly what I was trying to do :)